# Ac1300 Archer T6e, aren't there open source alternatives to broadcom drivers?

Tags: drivers, wireless, broadcom, pcie

Just like nvidia has the Nouveau driver alternative for its boards, aren't there alternatives for broadcom/TPLink pcie cards like mine: Ac1300 Archer T6e?

I'm very unconfortable in running proprietary drivers on my Ubuntu, specially the network one, which is the most dangerous and certainly have backdoors.

Comment: Nvidia help work on the `nouveau` drivers, broadcom aren't interested in that as don't see any $money in it as their products are *bottom-of-the-rung* (ie. sold on price)

Comment: @guiverc do you know any pcie card with 5ghz that has open source driver alternatives?

Comment: Sorry *shopping or hardware recommendations* are off-topic on this site - https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic , I believe I've seen them on Ubuntu Forums but I'm unsure sorry.  I don't know, would look at what's around & see if people have issues with those cards myself (but some brands sold on price like broadcom I'd probably skip..)